# Detection of a bundle by AppKernel.php symfony 2.5.6

Tags: php, symfony

i am having an issue with AppKernel and the bundle detector.

I am working in 2.5.6

Indeed, i have this error:
*Bundle "mainBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?*

But here is my AppKernel.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new theia\mainBundle\theiamainBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            //$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

I am having this issue when i try to link the routing.yml of the so called bundle with the app/config/routing.yml or routing_dev.yml.

To do this i add this in the app/.../routing.yml

```
t:
    resource: "@theiamainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Error Trace:

> in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2359   - public
>   function getBundle($name, $first = true) { if
>   (!isset($this->bundleMap[$name])) { throw new
>   \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Bundle "%s" does not exist or it is
>   not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles()
>   method of your %s.php file?', $name, get_class($this))); } if (true
>   === $first) { return $this->bundleMap[$name][0]; at Kernel ->getBundle ('mainBundle', false)  in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at
>   line 2332   +  at ControllerNameParser ->parse
>   ('mainBundle:security:login')  in
>   kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2384   +  at
>   ControllerResolver ->createController ('mainBundle:security:login') 
>   in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2047   +  at
>   ControllerResolver ->getController (object(Request))  in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php
>   at line 46   +  at TraceableControllerResolver ->getController
>   (object(Request))  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2969
>   +  at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2938   +  at HttpKernel
>   ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3087   +  at
>   ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)  in
>   kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2337   +  at Kernel
>   ->handle (object(Request))  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/web/app_dev.php
>   at line 28

here are the Logs trace

> INFO - Matched route "login_route" (parameters: "_controller": "mainBundle:security:login", "_route": "login_route") 
>   INFO - Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelReque
>   st".
>
> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Bundle
>   "mainBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to
>   add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?" at
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache
>   line 2359
>
> DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".  DEBUG -
>   Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".

Here are the Stack Trace:

> [1] InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "mainBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?
>       at n/a
>           in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2359

```
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->getBundle('mainBundle', false)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2332

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser->parse('mainBundle:security:login')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2384

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver->createController('mainBundle:security:login')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2047

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php line 46

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2969

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2938

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3087

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2337

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_projects/Symphony_projects/test/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Do you know were it could come from? Do you need any more files in order to help me?

Comment: Everything looks right.  Did you use the command for generating a bundle or did you make the file structure yourself?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html  also, depending on your environment you may need to flush the cache.  `php app/console cache:clear --env=[prod/dev]`  put either `--env=prod` or `--env=dev` at the end depending on which one you're in.  You can change you environment by modifying the htaccess in the web folder to point to app.php or app_dev.php.  Many code changes in prod won't work until the cache is flushed.

Comment: I did created the Bundle with the command.
I tried to use the specification after the cache clear but changes nothing :/

I forgot to say that i am in 2.5.6

Comment: Could you post the full error and trace?  Maybe the error is occurring somewhere else.  Because I'm not seeing any immediate glaring issues, but this is just a tiny slice of the entire framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes seems to have references to a "mainBundle" when specifying the controller, which should be "theiamainBundle":

`Matched route "login_route" (parameters: "_controller": "mainBundle:security:login", "_route": "login_route")`